# Kafka broker dying abruptly without any error log

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running kafka version 2.4.0. After 4-5 days of application running, it dies without any logs. We have 20gb box with xmx and xms set to 5gb. The GC activity of application is healthy and there are not GC issue. I don't see OOM killer being invoked as checked from system logs. There is 13gb available memory when process died.

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              19           5           0           0          13          13
Swap:              0           0           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this was vm.max_map_count limit (default being 65k) being hit by the application. We concluded this by looking at

```
jmx.java.nio.BufferPool.mapped.Count
```

metrics in jmx mbean.

Another way to check this is

```
cat /proc/<kafka broker pid>/maps | wc -l
```

Updating the max_map_count limit fixed the issue for us.

Another way to fix this issue could have been

1. Increasing the segment creation duration or number of records when segment is triggered.
2. Have more instances so that each instance gets assigned lesser number of paritions.